Integrate over an integrating function
I want to code this Formula in Python. I tried the following, but I am not sure whether this is correct, as I am not familiar with integrating in Python. Hope someone can help me with this!
#Here I simulate the function F
def simulate_F(T, r, age_dead, age_ci, x_age,N, a_y, b_y, c_y, mu_y, phi_d, m, b, k_1, k_2, phi_ci, a_hat, b_hat, c_hat, timestep,dt,t, T_r):
    F=np.zeros((N,timestep))             
    F_2 = np.zeros((N,timestep))       

    def mu_y(u):
        if x_age+t*dt<65:
            return a_y+b_y*2*u+c_y*3*u**2  # Customize as per your model
        else:
            return -(1-P)
    def lambda_d_hat_2(u):
        return (1+phi_d)*(1/b * np.exp((x_age+u-m)/b)+k_1 + k_1*(x_age+u))
    
    def lambda_d_hat_1(u):
        return (1+phi_d)*(1/b * np.exp((x_age+u-m)/b))
    
    def lambda_ci_hat(u):
        return (1+phi_ci)*(a_hat*np.exp(-((min(u,65)-b_hat)/c_hat)**2))
    
    # Inner integral: compute ∫_t^s (r - mu_y - lambda_d_hat) du
    def inner_integral_2(t, s):
        integrand = lambda u: r - mu_y(u) + lambda_d_hat_2(u)
        result, _ = quad(integrand, t, s)
        return result

        # Outer integral: compute F_2(t) = ∫_t^T exp(inner_integral(t, s)) ds
    def sim_F_2(t):
        outer_integrand = lambda s: np.exp(-inner_integral_2(t, s))
        result, _ = quad(outer_integrand, t, T)
        return result
    
    def inner_integral_1(t,s):
        integrand = lambda u: r-mu_y(u)+lambda_d_hat_1(u)+lambda_ci_hat(u)
        result,_ = quad(integrand, t,s)
        return result
    def sim_F_1(t):
        outer_integrand = lambda s: np.exp(-inner_integral_1(t,s))*(1+lambda_ci_hat(s)*p_ci*sim_F_2(s))
        result, _ = quad(outer_integrand,t,T)
        return result
        
    for n in range(0,N):
        for t_step in range(0,timestep):
            variable=t_step*dt
            if x_age+variable==age_dead[n]:
                F[n,t_step:]=0
                F_2[n,t_step:]=0
            elif x_age+variable==age_ci[n]:
                for j in range(t_step, T):
                    variable=j*dt
                    F[n,t_step]=sim_F_2(variable)
                    F_2[n,t_step]=sim_F_2(variable)
                break
            else:
                F[n,t_step]=sim_F_1(variable)
                F_2[n,t_step]=sim_F_2(variable)
    return F,F_2

F, F_2 = simulate_F(T, r, age_dead, age_ci, x_age,N, a_y, b_y, c_y, mu_y, phi_d, m, b, k_1, k_2, phi_ci, a_hat, b_hat, c_hat, timestep,dt,t, T_r)
print(F,F_2)

I tried to approach this in several ways and am not sure whether this is corect.

Looks like you've made a good start. My advice to getting this working is to put that aside for the moment and look at simplified versions of the problem, starting with a very much simpler problem and then adding elements until you get back to the original problem. E.g. omitting the second term (1 + indicator(a = 1) ...), and omitting some of the terms in the exponent, to start with, and/or setting the constants which appear to neutral values such as 1 or 0. When you get the restricted problem to work correctly, then start relaxing the restrictions until you have the general problem again.
